# I get this error "Unable to load assembly group" when deploying the following Branding101 Sandbox solution

Tags: branding

I'm following this Branding example - [Creating the Branding101 Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg447066.aspx#SP14DeployBrandingSolutionsSandbox_Creating)

When I get to the Deploy, I get this error in Visual Studio

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add
>   Solution': Unable to load assembly
>   group. The user assembly group
>   provider threw an exception while
>   trying to provide user assemblies for
>   the specified assembly group.

In the SharePoint Logs I get this...

```
-  - Unable to load assembly group. The user assembly group provider threw an exception while trying to provide user assemblies for the specified assembly group. - Assembly group id: ", GroupId = "6F4390B205E741A99987A7E415C6A35F-/IYL9cV+BAGCtKagtmUoEKm28+0/iaIbJdAbSB5L6og="" - Inner Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId, String strListName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Undirty()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType typeCatalog)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.GetSolutionInfoFromGallery(Guid siteId, Guid solutionId, String solutionHash, String& fileName, String& hash, Byte[]& fileBytes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeLightweightSolutionAssemblyGroupProvider.GetAssembliesInGroup(Guid siteId, String assemblyGroupId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAssemblyCacheManager.EnsureUserCodeAssemblyGroupIsCached(Guid siteId, SPUserCodeAssemblyGroupId userCodeAssemblyGroupId)
```

Can someone help me with deploying this test solution?

****Update****
The only difference between the example and my solution was I had create a new web application on port 33333 and created a new blank site. I just changed to deploy to port 80 and it worked. I would still be interested if there is an explanation for this though. I guess there must be some difference between the web app I created on 33333 and the defautl one created at 80.

Comment: If you scroll over a bit, you see that your actual error is "Access is denied." so it has to do with your permissions

Comment: Do both port 80 and 33333 use the same application pool?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the sandboxed code service?

Check what account and permissions your sandbox code service is running under.

Comment: I had restarted the service... do I check the account and permissions through SP admin or elsewhere?

Comment: Should be in CA->Security->Service Accounts

Answer (score 1):

The sandboxed service unpacks the DLLs of a sandboxed solution when the solution is first accessed and caches them in a subfolder at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\UCCache. On each subsequent access of the same solution, they are retrieved from there. If a server goes a while without a request for that solution, the subfolder is deleted. I wonder if the user account under which the sandboxed service is running has rights to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service runs with a specific account. Add this account to the web application (you’re using to deploy the solution) in Central Administration, User Policy, with full control. Perform an iisreset afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Also stumbled over this yesterday, this article helped me : http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2011/04/error-unable-to-load-assembly-group.html